# maintaining order in json (python flask)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I made a sorted dictionary to pass through json to a javascript, however, it seems whenever I throw it into a `json.dumps()` it changes its order into alphabetical by keys. It is critical that I keep it in a certain order or else it will not work.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Objects in JSON are an [**unordered** collection of key:value pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) (same as dictionaries in Python), so you should use a different data structure if the order is relevant.

A structure like this (in JSON) would work:

```
{ "columns" : [ "id", "name", "age"],
  "rows" : [[ "john", "John Doe", 42],
            [ "jane", "Jane Miller", 28]
    ]
}
```